# Pass the id of href into the href link

Tags: php, html, anchor, href

So here is my problem.I want the id of the href which is taken dynamically to be printed in the url.
My code of category.php:

**CATEGORY.PHP**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    echo '<a id="' . $row['topic_id'] . '"  href="category.php?id=' . 
         $_SESSION['id'] . '&check1=//what should i put here?">;
}
```

all i want is for check1 to have the id of each link seperately so if i have 3 links(depends on the database) the 2nd link will have id=2 and i want to print id=2 the next time category.php is loaded.

**BUT**

Notice that all id are first printed and then someone will choose one of these links.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, you want check1 to have all the other links ID's or what?

Comment: Its not really clear what _think_ you actually want to place in the `check1=` position. I would imagine so you can find the same row again you would need `$row['topic_id'] ` in there so `"check1=$row['topic_id']"`

Comment: Please explain a bit more your problem so we can help.

Comment: The answer is in your question itself.

`what should i put here?` = `$row['topic_id']`

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: sorry for any confusion. I dont want to put $check1=$row['topic_id'] because then $check1 it will just take the last value of $row['topic_id'] and i want to print 3 links and then the user choose what link to press.lets say i have link1 link2 link3 every link has $row['topic_id']=1, ..=2, ..=3 if i put $check1 to take the value of $row['topic_id'] then it will always take the value 3

Comment: No, it won't, In your loop your `$row['topic_id']` changes each time the loop is run through, try it and you will see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already doing it in other places.
It's called *concatenation* - All that PHP does is output dynamically generated HTML. This means that within the quotes of your `echo` construct you can concatenate anywhere.

All you have to do is add it to the URL as you did with ID:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<a id="'. $row['topic_id'] .'" href="category.php?id='. $_SESSION['id'] .'&check1='. $row['topic_id'] .'"></a>'
}
```

your `$row['topic_id']` should be different with every iteration. the `$row` variable gets set to a new

This will output the same `$row['topic_id']` as the `id` attribute of the link but it will also append it as a `$_GET` parameter in your *category.php*.

If you do not know what gets passed on in the `$_GET` array you could always do a `print_r($_GET)` anywhere in the script since `$_GET` always gets set (even without query params, it'll just be empty).

It could be that it is unclear to me what you're asking, it could also be that you want the actual `primary key` `id` field in which case you'll just have to swap out the last bit:

`&check1=$row['topic_id']`

with whatever your ID field is named, probably something along the lines of:

`&check1=$row['id']`

where `id` would be the actual `id` of the row in the database table.

Comment: i was trying to explain exactly that if i do it like this then $row['topic_id'] will just take the last value of $row['topic_id] and i dont want always to take the last value

Comment: Doing this should take the CURRENT value of `topic_id` from the current iteration over your result set

Comment: @Johnny could you post the output of what you get back in a `$row['topic_id']` - I'm sure that what I'm doing currently is correct, I'll update my answer with some information

Comment: Thank you i didnt know that and i am preety amateur on php.Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Johnny If you still read this, could you tell me what the actual solution was? We all start somewhere anyways but I'm curious to know what the itch was ;)